# Android bundle.putLong("id",id) is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bundle

I am trying to send value as a parameter from one fragment to another using bundle but bundle is not is not putting in bundle. i tried to get value in next fragment but value was **0** then i debugged and got that value is not saving in bundle. screenshot is attached.

**Here is code**

```
switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.store_gift_promo:
        {
            Fragment fragment = new GiftPromotion();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("id",id);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }


   }
```

**Please help me solve the problem.**

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. The only explanation I can think is the value of `id` changed between line 3 and 4? Multithreading involved or time travel possibility?

Comment: @Shaishav i don't know i am also surprised!.

Comment: Are you using `Instant Run` because it has a lot of bugs currently (faced them myself). if yes, uninstall the app and rerun the code.

Comment: let me check. But it is working in previous fragment :-(

Comment: if you have int and expect long, convert it and then check if it is still working

Comment: @Andrei T it is declared as long like, long id;

Comment: This is surprising really.. Try logging debug the bundle value.. Just in case..

Comment: @MalikRizwan Did you solve the mystery?

Comment: @Shaishav yes you were right i did clean the project uninstall the app restart tool and everything was fine. i don't know where was the issue.

Comment: `Instant Run` is currently a bit buggy. I've even faced an issue where all my resource strings were jumbled!

Answer (score 0):

Try it in another way like this:

```
GiftPromotion gp = GiftPromotion.newInstance(id);
```

in GiftPromotion:

```
public static GiftPromotion newInstance(long id) {
    GiftPromotion f = new GiftPromotion ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong("longValue", id);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

while retrieving in onCreate of fragment:

```
long lId = getArguments().getLong("longValue", 0L);
```